# Singleton possible memory leak blazor component

Tags: c#, singleton, blazor

I have the following singleton:

```
  public class StockService
{
    public StockService()
    {
        
    }

    private List<string> Stock { get; set; }

    public void ReloadStock()
    {      
            Stock = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"ExternalStock.csv").ToList();
    }
}
```

Pretty simple service that loads product stock from a csv file and saves the results in a list.

The problem arises when i reload this stock it increases the memory amount every time its reloaded? i would expect it to replace the list and the 'old' list would be forgotten about but this doesn't seem to be the case and the memory just increases exponentially.

The blazor controller that i used as a test to call the ReloadStock function:

```
    public partial class TestComponent
{

    [Inject] public Services.StockService StockService { get; set; }

    public List<string> ProductsToWatch { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public string ProductCodeTextBox { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      
    }
    
    public void AddToList()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProductCodeTextBox)) return;
        ProductsToWatch.Add(ProductCodeTextBox);
       
    }

    public void ReloadStock()
    {
        StockService.ReloadStock();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, garbage collection will free up the memory of the List once you reassign it to a new reference. In practice, garbage collection may take some time. As a test, try calling `GC.Collect()` in your ReloadStock method.

Comment: I did this originally thinking it was a delayed response from the GC however even after calling the GC the initial load takes it to around 350 mb then after the second reload it peaks at 580mb then the garbage collector is called then goes down to 528mb i would of expected it to go back down to 350 ish? i've left it running to see if the GC is called again but after 10 minutes it's still not been called again, im stumped!